# Black–Scholes but probably basic stats

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

[image][image]

Hello friends! I'm rusty (bad) with my statistics and this problem is bugging me, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Just really bad at figuring out how the 1-N() gets transformed into the 2nd line.

EDIT: sorry I got too excited and didn't ask about part (d). Any explanation on where the first 2 equations (St) come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eltigrechino's answer is correct after the correction by Ian. That is, if your distribution is normally distributed ~N($\mu, \sigma$) then it is a property of normal distributions that 1 - N(x) = N(-x). In particular, using your expression, we have: x = $\frac{lnK - lnS_0 - (\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$ Note that $lnK - lnS_0 = ln(\frac{K}{S_0})$ then -x = $\frac{-lnK + lnS_0 + (\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$ = $\frac{ln(\frac{S_0}{K}) + (\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$. Since this quantity is $d_2$ in the Black-Scholes model, we see that P($S_T$ > K) = N($d_2$).

To get the first two equations in (d) note that we may write $ln(S_T) = ln(S_0) + (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})T + \sigma\sqrt{T}Z$ where Z ~ N(0, 1) since this will be normally distributed with the apprpriate mean and variance. Exponentiating both sides gives you the result.

Comment: thank you user7348! I got too overconfident and neglected to ask about part (d). Can I get a hand on it too?

Comment: I could explain how to get the first two questions, but are you familiar with Ito's Formula?

Comment: @user240311 You don't need Ito's formula, see my updated answer.

Comment: @user240311 Could you upvote me?

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution is symmetric about its mean. Therefore you can flip the CDF calculation as follows

$1 - \Phi(x) = \Phi(-x) $ where $\Phi$ represents the CDF of a $N(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution.

Edit: whoops forgot to flip the sign, thanks

Comment: I think you mean $1-\Phi(x)=\Phi(-x)$.

Comment: yea I just remembered that. 1−Φ(x)=Φ(−x) !!! Thanks for the quick help guys!